# String to ascii conversion, xor it with another integer. Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, xor

I have a string from which using for-loop ,each char has been converted
into ascii and then xored with an integer. I converted each output back to its 
relevant char. I need to print all those output characters all at once on the label
field in the iphone GUI.

I not able to get the part where I need to print them all onto the label field.
Here is the code. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

```
-(IBAction)result {

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [sword text]];

for ( NSInteger i=0; i<[str length]; i++ )
{
    unichar c = [str characterAtIndex:i];

    int asciiCode1 = ([kword.text intValue]);

    int z = asciiCode1 ^ c;

     int a = (char)z;
}
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %c", a];
```

Answer (score 1):

you are declaring your variables inside the for loop, so they are dying before you actually go to use them.

You can make an NSMutableString and append it with the newly xor'd character. Also you may want to say

```
char a = (char)z;
```

instead of

```
int a = (char)z;
```

you can make a copy of the original string and then xor each character individually as well, if you wanted.

Comment: k. So I think i need to use an array to put the output characters. I want to print all the characters at once onto the label field. I tried that but in vain. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Don't use an array. Just use a mutable string. That way you can directly set the text of the label to the string.

Do you know how to declare a new, append to, and use an NSMutableString?

Comment: Am not sure how to do that. Am trying to to use the append func and get the reqd result. But am not sure if am going in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, use the append function. Make sure it's inside your for loop! If you post your new code, or email me I'll give you a hand: ultifinitus@gmail.com